# Can not identify iPhone provisioning profile

Tags: ios, provisioning

I have two distribution profiles one for app store and other for creating ad hoc. I forgot to name these profiles properly and i cant distinguish which is app store profile and which is ad hoc. Is there any way to find out this using there two provisioning profiles? I dont have access to developer account so that I could download both profiles from there. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would like ti know this is correct. 1) Open .mobileprovision using text edit. 2) When I see key like "<key>ProvisionedDevices</key>" I can ensure it is a ad-hoc profile and if i does not find this one I can determine this was a app store profile. Is this true?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, When you archive the app you select between provisioning for app store and for enterprise or ad-hoc distribution. 
Also another trick is when you select the provisioning profile and try to run it on the iphone the App store one will not install on the device, but the ad-hoc provisioning profile will allow you to put the executable on the phone.

Answer (score 0):

My finding is

If a profile is Ad-Hoc distribution profile, then there will be tags like

```
<key>ProvisionedDevices</key>
<array>
    <string>UDID1</string>
    <string>UDID2</string>
    <string>UDID3</string>
</array>
<key>TeamIdentifier</key>
```

here UDID1, UDID2 are unique ids of devices added to this profile.

Developer profile also have this kind of 'ProvisionedDevices' tag. But a Appstore distribution profile will not have 'ProvisionedDevices' tag in provisioning file. So we can open the mobile provisioning file and search for tag 'ProvisionedDevices' to identify which is the profile.